# Displacement makes geometry visible even with shade smooth set

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry, displacement, shader-nodes, smooth

I'm trying to apply voronoi noise displacement to a mesh. See Below, I have a very simple shader node setup. With shade smooth set, I can still see the mesh geometry, which looks pretty bad.

I've tried playing with Auto Smooth, but that has no effect. Interestingly, I don't really see this on something like a UV sphere, but it's very noticeable on the Monkey/Suzanne mesh, which is pictured below. Even more frustrating, some areas seem to shade properly while others do not.

How can I get everything to shade smooth when displacing with voronoi noise?

[image: example with node setup]

Comment: In the Material panel > Settings > Displacement, I think you need to choose Displacement Only. Also it doesn't work in Eevee

Comment: Using Cycles, forgot to mention.

It's a shame that I can't use Displacement and Bump. Using Displacement Only changes things a bit and I'll lose the ability to add fine detail, but I might be able to work with it.